# Django AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, django-views

When visiting a url it returns a error mentioned in the question title.

The View itself is a ListView.

When i debuged the view, it only looped through the dispatcher function and return the following error without getting to queryset.
Here's the code.

**ListView**

```
class MailingListView(ListView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    # model = MailingList
    template_name = 'mailinglist/mailing_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MailingList.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return reverse('user:login')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Model**

```
class MailingList(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=user_model,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('mailinglist:manage_list', kwargs={'pk': self.id})

    def user_can_use_mailinglist(self, user):
        return user == self.owner
```

**Traceback**

```
> Internal Server Error: /mailinglist/ Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 34, in inner
>     response = get_response(request)   File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
> line 93, in __call__
>     response = self.process_response(request, response)   File /venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py",
> line 26, in process_response
>     if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: add your error traceback

Answer (score 4):

reverse() returns a string. But you are supposed to return HTTP responses.

Change in `dispatch` in `MailingListView`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user:login'))
```

Comment: Thank you it helped. Would upvote if had enough rep.

Comment: You may accept it. This will help another developer to understand this solution works

Comment: This answer should be accepted man... I was blowing my brain what I was doing wrong in my class based view then I found this. Thanks bro!